# Sharing Test Cases Kiwi-tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I want to know if I can share the documentation of a test plan and test cases created from the website https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/ to people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if I can share the documentation of a test plan and test cases created from the website https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/ to people.

As the URL suggests anyone can create an account and access this website so you can share any TestPlan, TestCase and TestRun you wish. By default Kiwi TCMS requires the user to be logged in because in most environments this information is not for public consumption.

If you are asking if you can send URLs to anonymous users for them to have read-only access the answer is Yes but that needs to be configured. Because of the reasons outlined above this is not the default setting on https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org

On the contrary, we have another instance used by our own team which has the necessary setting configured and allows anonymous read-only access, see: https://tcms.kiwitcms.org/plan/1/conference-readiness#testcases

*Disclaimer: this answer has been provided to you by a Kiwi TCMS team member.*